# Does fprintf() work for writing in a pipe, or I must always use write()?

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe, posix

Keep in mind that when using `fprintf()` I'm aware that I need to pass the file descriptor for writing to the pipe. I just have the doubt and wish to know right now; I don't really have any kind of sample code.

In addition, I want to know if functions such as fputc(), fputs() will also work.

Comment: Just remember that, since pipe() gives you a file descriptor, you need to use [fdopen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen).  But sure:  fprintf(), fputc(), fputs() and friends should work just fine - no problem :)

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 , I had no idea that they were different things, now I know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fdopen()` to convert a file descriptor to a `FILE *`, and then use all the stdio functions.

```
int pipefd[2];
pipe(pipefd);

FILE *pipeout = fdopen(pipefd[1], "w");
fprintf(pipeout, "Message written to the pipe\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`fprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) requires a file stream (`FILE *`).  When you create a pipe, you get two file descriptors.  File descriptors are not the same as streams.

You can use the POSIX [`fdopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) function to create a file stream from a file descriptor; you can then use `fprintf()` on that file stream — or any of the other standard I/O functions that take an explicit file stream argument and write to the stream.  You can't use `fseek()`; you'll get an error (`ESPIPE` — illegal seek).

You can (in theory) use the POSIX [`dprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html) function to write directly to a file descriptor — if your system supports it.

Comment: Thanks! the fact that I can use dprintf() is really good to know!